# How to pass kwargs while using map function?

Tags: python

As above, I want to use map function to apply a function to a bunch of things and collect results in a list. However, I don't see how can I pass kwargs to that function.

For concreteness:

```
map(fun, elements)
```

What about kwargs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) instead of a `map`.

```
(fun(x, **kwargs) for x in elements)
```

e.g.

```
reduce(fun(x, **kwargs) for x in elements)
```

Or if you're going straight to a list, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) instead:

```
[fun(x, **kwargs) for x in elements]
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is already answered at [Python `map` and arguments unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874244/python-map-and-arguments-unpacking)

The map does not exactly support named variable, though can handle multiple variable based on position.

Since Python 3 the standard map can list arguments of multi-argument separately

```
map(fun, listx, listy, listz)
```

It is though less convenient for variable length list of named variables, especially in presence of `**kwargs` in the function signature. You can, though,
introduce some intermediate function to pack separately positional and named arguments. For one line solution with lambda see [Python `map` and arguments unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874244/python-map-and-arguments-unpacking)
If you are not proficient with lambda, you can go as below

```
def foldarg(param): 
    return f(param[0], **param[1])
list(map(foldarg, elements))
```

where `elements` is something like

```
[[[1,2], dict(x=3, y=4)],
[[-2,-2], dict(w=3, z=4)]]
```

For unnamed variables list you can also use itertools.starmap

Comment: Are you saing that I have to create a list in which I repeat the kwargs?